# Automatic notification without an API

Tags: notifications

My school is using a website to manage grades, homework and communication with teachers. Because there is no way to get automatic notification, most students have to use it daily to check manually if there's an update (new message, new grade, etc). Since their service has no API, what should I do to get automatic notifications.

Is there any tools available that automatically notify you (by email or rss feed) of any change in a page by authentifying and checking if the value of a specific field changed?

Should I code my own script?
Is there any tool or library out there that could make this task easier?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.changedetection.com/

Not sure if it works for secure websites, though.

Comment: Thank you for the link but it effectively does not work on secure websites. It's not very precise either and you can't specify a certain part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I just found something interesting. It's called [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). It's an application framework that makes data-mining and structured data extraction easier.

Has anyone experience with Scrapy? Could it solve my problem?